# Passing a parameter to Identity Server 4 Login Page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I have a client application that is using IDSVR4 for authentication. I need to store the user's username(in a different process from the login through IDSVR) on the client in a session or whatevr other client-side data storage mech so the user doesn't have to enter the details everytime he logs in from that specific browser. 
How can i pass the username from the client to identity server?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add the username to the request parameters. If you're using asp.net in the client, you may use the notification event `RedirectToIdentityProvider` then add your username to the ProtocolMessage. Something like this:

```
RedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
{
    context.ProtocolMessage.Parameters['username'] = "John";
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Any value you add to the parameters will be accessible in IdentityServer through the `IIdentityServerInteractionService` method `GetAuthorizationContextAsync`

Like this, in your IdentityServer controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string returnUrl){
    var context = await _interaction.GetAuthorizationContextAsync(returnUrl);
    var username = context.Parameters['username'];
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, sorry took me a while to mark this work caught up to me. Also both answers were great, marked this for the completeness and clarity in implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass custom parameter to the authorize endpoint , for code sample you can refer to my reply [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53629114/5751404) .

If you are not using the OpenID Connect OWIN Middleware , you can directly put the custom parameter into the authorize request :

```
http://localhost:xxxx/account/login?returnUrl=/connect/authorize/callback?client_id=mvc2&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A49459%2Fsignin-oidc&response_type=code%20id_token&scope=openid%20profile%20api1%20offline_access&response_mode=form_post&nonce=xxxx&state=xxxx
```

On identity server side you can parse `returnUrl` and easily get the parameter .