# Adding Custom values in Identity Server 4 Connect/token endpoint

Tags: c#, .net, identityserver4

i have implemented the Identity server 4 .. one thing on which i am stuck is currently
connect/token endpoint provides the following fields

```
{
  "id_token": "id toekn value",
  "access_token": "access token value",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "refresh_token": "a refresh token",
  "scope": "some scopes"
}
```

however i want to add some more fields in this  like

```
{
  "id_token": "id toekn value",
  "access_token": "access token value",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "refresh_token": "a refresh token",
  "scope": "some scopes",
  "id":"any id",
  "url":"any url"
}
```

any way to intercept this call and add custom fileds???

Comment: any one there to help?????

Comment: Why do you need this? You typically use the UserInfo enpoint to add user specific claims or you can add it to the IDToken?

Comment: its the requirements the client app is getting id paramtere from this and proceeding

Comment: Still, I don't get why you want to do that? Why can't you include it in the UserInfo endpoint or in the ID-token?, in the client, you typically let the OpenIDConnect handler call the TokenEndpoint, and not you as a developer.

Comment: its done by implementing the ICustomTokenRequestValidator

Comment: basically its the requirement by Inferno Server... can't change its requirement

Comment: @ToreNestenius https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73474403/how-to-create-client-with-jwk-sets-and-how-to-get-the-client-token-identity


any help on this???

Comment: Sorry, can't help you with that.

Comment: please check this post i think it will help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53612846/pass-custom-header-value-to-identityserver4-login/53629114#53629114