# How to create client with JWK sets?? and how to get the client token?? identity server 4

Tags: identityserver4, duende-identity-server

i am creating a client with JWk set in a following way

```
new Client
                {
                    ClientId = "infernoSystemClient",
                    ClientName = "Client Credentials Client",
                     RequireRequestObject = true,

                    ClientSecrets =
                    {
                    
                        new Secret
                        {
                            // JWK formatted RSA key
                            Type = IdentityServerConstants.SecretTypes.JsonWebKey,

                            Value = "{'kty': 'RSA','alg': 'RS384','n': 'vjbIzTqiY8K8zApeNng5ekNNIxJfXAue9BjoMrZ9Qy9m7yIA-tf6muEupEXWhq70tC7vIGLqJJ4O8m7yiH8H2qklX2mCAMg3xG3nbykY2X7JXtW9P8VIdG0sAMt5aZQnUGCgSS3n0qaooGn2LUlTGIR88Qi-4Nrao9_3Ki3UCiICeCiAE224jGCg0OlQU6qj2gEB3o-DWJFlG_dz1y-Mxo5ivaeM0vWuodjDrp-aiabJcSF_dx26sdC9dZdBKXFDq0t19I9S9AyGpGDJwzGRtWHY6LsskNHLvo8Zb5AsJ9eRZKpnh30SYBZI9WHtzU85M9WQqdScR69Vyp-6Uhfbvw','e': 'AQAB','use': 'sig','key_ops': ['verify'],'ext': true,'kid': 'b41528b6f37a9500edb8a905a595bdd7'}"
                        }
                    },

                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,
                    AllowedScopes = { "system/*.read" }
                }
```

and calling the same client in a following way..

my client app is calling this end point /connect/token with these parameters

```
client_assertion=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJFUzM4NCIsImtpZCI6IjRiNDlhNzM5ZDFlYjExNWIzMjI1ZjRjZjliZWI2ZDFiIn0.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.m-nWIEKV1sv6zxX72jaq5L12Owixl-nxFYfOkINGyUPx-qZH2uJYUQC-iKJedpJRUZGyzyqWK1OelYu-Ze1w38gwMss1xGQ50esom6xd8dYyz6-XYhT45F7uDfiySDLx&client_assertion_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Aclient-assertion-type%3Ajwt-bearer&grant_type=client_credentials&scope=system%2F%2A.read
```

but its says invalid client..
when i see logs on identity server side it say

Invalid HTTP request for token endpoint No client identifier found

Comment: @ToreNestenius any helpp on this???

Comment: Maybe add `client_id=infernoSystemClient` to the url parameters?

Comment: actually this URL is created by Inferno Server (the client app)automatically... its standard one

Comment: Ok, then maybe this can help: https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v6/tokens/authentication/jwt/

Comment: follow the exact same steps... except i just used this secret key way
new Secret
                        {
                            // JWK formatted RSA key
                            Type = IdentityServerConstants.SecretTypes.JsonWebKey,

                            Value = "{my client app provided key'}"
                        }


instead of using both ways to have multiple secret entries in client secret table

Answer (score 0):

By Default **client_secret_basic** and **client_secret_post** are supported in Identity Server(IDS) Authentication Method. Following is snippet from openid-configuration of Identity Server.

"token_endpoint_auth_methods_supported": [
"client_secret_basic",
"client_secret_post",
"private_key_jwt"
]

In order to generate access token successfully using JWT (client_assertion) and JWK, you need to enable **"private_key_jwt"** auth method in IDS. You can activate feature by injecting secret parser and validator in configure services.

```
     public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
        //IReplayCache DI required for PrivateKeyJwtSecretValidator
        services.TryAddTransient<IReplayCache, DefaultReplayCache>();
        
        //Add Secret Parser and Validator for JWT validation
services.AddIdentityServer().AddSecretParser<JwtBearerClientAssertionSecretParser>().AddSecretValidator<PrivateKeyJwtSecretValidator>();
        }
```